# docker build how to run intermediate containers with centos:systemd

Tags: docker, zend-framework, ibm-cloud, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image that is based on `centos:systemd`. In my Dockerfile I am running a command that depends on systemd running, this fails with the following error:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
error: %pre(mod-php-7.1-apache2-zend-server-7.1.7-16.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package mod-php-7.1-apache2-zend-server-7.1.7-16.x86_64
```

how can I get the intermediate containers to run with `--privileged` and mapping `-v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro` ?

If I comment out the installer and just run the container and manually execute the installer it works fine.

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM centos/systemd
COPY ./ZendServer-9.1.0-RepositoryInstaller-linux.tar.gz /opt
RUN tar -xvf /opt/ZendServer-9.1.0-RepositoryInstaller-linux.tar.gz -C /opt/
RUN /opt/ZendServer-RepositoryInstaller-linux/install_zs.sh 7.1 java --automatic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your installer needs `systemd` running, I think you will need to launch a container with the base `centos/systemd` image, manually run the commands, and then save the result using [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/). The base image `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are not run while child images are getting built, but they do run if you launch a container and make your changes. After manually executing the installer, run `docker commit {my_intermediate_container} {my_image}:{my_version}`, replacing the bits in curly braces with the container name/hash, your desired image name, and image version.

You might also be able to change your Dockerfile to launch init before running your installer. I am not sure if that will work here in the context of building an image, but that would look like:

```
FROM centos/systemd
COPY ./ZendServer-9.1.0-RepositoryInstaller-linux.tar.gz /opt
RUN tar -xvf /opt/ZendServer-9.1.0-RepositoryInstaller-linux.tar.gz -C /opt/ \
    && /usr/sbin/init \
    && /opt/ZendServer-RepositoryInstaller-linux/install_zs.sh 7.1 java --automatic
```

Comment: Thanks @wmorrell will try that now, forgot about committing it manually, might be a good workaround until I can figure out how to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

A LAMP stack inside a docker container does not need systemd - I have made to work with the [docker-systemctl-replacement script](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement). It is able to start and stop a service according to what's written in the *.service file. You could try it with what the ZendServer is normally doing outside a docker container.